# Jquery mobile - Icons disappear on rel="external"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, icons

I've been encountering some problems with icon appearance
on my project, I have a multi-page html which i can only go with the attribute `rel="external"` (only way move to a multi-page html).

The problem is that whenever I click the link with the `rel="external"`, the page loads without the icon pictures, instead, there are some empty circles which supposed to contain the icons.
this problem continues to occur throughout the other pages which shown after that `rel="external"` link.

Note that before i click the `rel="external"` link, the icons work perfectly fine..

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of rel="external" causes a full page refresh, so the target HTML page should include in its header tag all the JS and CSS required for proper appearance and functioning.

Could you check whether the jQM JS and CSS files are included  in the target HTML files?

I hope this helps.